# Where do I need to use dispatch_async on main_queue?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I generally use the following code to update UI change or pop up some dialog box:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
{
  ...
}
```

I am clear to use it in the following scenario:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

  //Add some method process in global queue - normal for data processing

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
    //Add method, task you want perform on mainQueue
    //Control UIView, IBOutlet all here

    });

 //Add some method process in global queue - normal for data processing

});
```

However, how about the other cases, e.g., in some closures or callback functions?

```
autocomplete(sbYouTube.text!) { (results, status) -> Void in

                if status == "OK"
                {
                    if let results = results
                    {
                        addAutocompletes(results)
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                        self.tvAutocomplete.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog("%@", status)
                }
            }
```

or

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
     {
         self.downloadedSize = totalBytesWritten
         self.sizeToDownload = totalBytesExpectedToWrite

         self.downloadProcess.angle = Double(totalBytesWritten) * 360.0 / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
         self.lbPercent.text = "\(totalBytesWritten * 100 / totalBytesExpectedToWrite)%"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: You should always dispatch_async to the main queue if you are updating UI. For example, your last snippet sets self.lbPercent.text which we can presume is a UILabel. So that has to be done on the main thread. You're free to ignore this if you know for sure that you are already on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. dispatch_get_main_queue() function will return the main queue where your UI is running.
2. The dispatch_get_main_queue() function is very useful for updating the iOS app’s UI as UIKit methods are not thread safe (with a few exceptions) so any calls you make to update UI elements must always be done from the main queue.

for more see this link

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/9/4/back-to-the-main-thread-dispatch_get_main_queue

Answer (score 0):

You are safe to use this block:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
    //Add method, task you want perform on mainQueue
    //Control UIView, IBOutlet all here

    });
```

everywhere, in closures and callback functions. It makes sure that the code in it gets executed on the main thread. You can also use `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.performBlock` as it does the same thing